# Stop simple JavaScript slideshow after one loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, setinterval

I know very little about `JavaScript` at all, but I'm looking for a solution to a simple code that I'd like to use. I'm not trying to execute any slides or fades, just a simple slideshow that switches from one image to the next. I want the slideshow to play through just once, and then stop on the last image in the sequence. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .next()
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

As I said, it's a very simple code. The first `GIF` runs only once, the second `GIF` loops. I would like the slideshow to stop on the looping `GIF`. I'm wondering if the '3000' (which I know corresponds to the length of each slide) can be changed to accomplish what I'm looking for. Or else adding a stop function... which I don't know how to write.

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
  <img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/e2c4bbaeb781a3b834cd09549595393f/
        tumblr_noy3q3l1dy1uwyyx9o2_1280.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/1d6495399687801067d62c83c4218644/
        tumblr_noy3q3l1dy1uwyyx9o1_1280.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the context for this code?

Comment: I'm running a series of images as a header, and would like it to stop on the final image. Is that what you mean by context?

Comment: Add your HTML, and/or a fiddle and your question will get answered accurately and promptly.

Comment: if there are only 2 images, why not just hide the first after a certain amount of time then unhide the other?

Comment: Do you have the link to such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have made this with the objective of being as clear and simple for you to understand as possible, (since you new to js...)

**JS/Jquery:**

```
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(playSlideShow, 3000);

        function playSlideShow() {

            var currImgContainer = $('.showImg');
            if (!$(currImgContainer).hasClass('lastImg')) {
                $('.showImg').removeClass('showImg').next().addClass('showImg');
                setTimeout(playSlideShow, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
```

So here we find the imgContainer(div) with the class "showImg", then using *chaining*, we remove the class and add it to the next imgContainer(div). Therefore toggling the CSS to show/hide the image until it finds the div that has the class "lastImg".

**CSS:**

```
    .slideShow > div:not(.showImg) {
        display: none;
    }

    .showImg {
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slideShow" id="slideshow">
    <div class="showImg">
        <img src="Images/img1.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="Images/img2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="Images/img3.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="lastImg">
        <img src="Images/img4.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you can have as many images as you want, just make sure the last div has class "lastImg" and the first one has the class "showImg".

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lf7cfkn/3/)

Hope it helps...

Comment: This code runs really smoothly, which I like. But instead of staying on the last image, the whole slideshow disappears. I'd like for it to just stay on the final image.

Comment: Oops, my original fiddle didnt have "lastImg" set in the html, i have edited it, check link now...

Comment: Awesome, that totally fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, Thank you for updating as correct answer, and good luck on the web/Javascript journey, its really fun and powerful.

Comment: it's a feature for me :) I was trying to hide the last photo after slideshow finishes its loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var intervalID = null;
var iterator = 0;
var intervalDuration = 3000;
var slideshow = $('#slideshow');
var divs = slideshow.find('div');

//divs.filter(':gt(0)').hide();
divs.eq(iterator).show();

intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    divs.eq(iterator).hide();
    iterator += 1;
    if (iterator === divs.length - 1) { clearInterval(intervalID); }
    divs.eq(iterator).show();
}, intervalDuration);
```

```css
#slideshow > div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/Codepen/PIXI/0.4/images/JS.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/Codepen/PIXI/0.4/images/PIXI.jpg" />
    </div>
<div>
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/Codepen/PIXI/0.4/images/JS.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML structure is same as yours but the only thing that I have changed are the image sources (tumbler images weren't loading for me). But JavaScript has been changed completely.

Add as many *DIVs* as you like in your HTML to test it out. Hope it helps.

Update #1:

- Added CSS to hide the `divs` by default.
- Increased the `intervalDuration` to `3000`. Just to make sure there is ample time for the images to be loaded.
- Commented the `filter` line of JS.
- Added another JS line right below the previous `filter` line.
- This update should also load your GIF only when it is needed to appear, hence will not be running in the background.

Let me if this works.

Comment: This works great, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

One weird observation, however, is that when the page first loads, you see the briefest glimpse of the second (last) image before the first one appears. Not sure what might be causing that...

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to remove the unnecessary `console.log();` calls in my code, had put them there for demonstration / debugging purposes only.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. what do you mean by *begin playing in the background*. Second image already *displays after* the first image i.e. after the allotted 2 seconds time.

Comment: The *flicker* happens because JS is waiting to be executed. Usually it loads *after* the document has fully loaded. And by default, `img` tags display the images as soon as they get loaded.