# Dynamic Bootstrap product slider

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I know PHP well, but can't make this slider dynamic. The problem is, I have to run two foreach loops, but I don't want to run two loops. I just want to handle it in one loop.

This is the code (I commented on every div):

```
<div class="container">           
 <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
         <?php foreach($product as $pro):?>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="col-item">
                            <div class="photo">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                            </div>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
         <?php endforeach;?>
                </div><!--end of row-->
            </div><!--end of item active!-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">   
    <!-- I don't want to run this new loop. I want to handle it in a single loop -->
         <?php foreach($productnew as $pronew):?>                                            
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="col-item">
                            <div class="photo">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                <?php endforaech;?>    
              </div><!-- end item--->
            </div><!-- end of item row-->
        </div><!--end of carousel inner-->

    </div><!--end of carousel example-->
</div><!--end of container-->
```

Comment: You have `$product` and `$productnew`, they are two different variables. How would you handle that in one loop? Or is `$product` == `$productnew`?

Comment: yeah i wante to remove that second loop and wanna to handle in one loop

Comment: actually i wanna to use bootstrape thumbnail slider here is the http://learningphp.org/ecommerce/     like this site using product slider http://learningphp.org/ecommerce/

Comment: Did you intend to have only 2 slides in the carousel? Each `<div class="item">` is one slide, and you only have 2 of them in your code.

Comment: it will coming from database dynamic,each row will have 4 product

Comment: active item will have 4 product after that next row will also have 4 product

Comment: this is the thing which i want you can veiw it http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider

Comment: Ok. So why you have 2 arrays? Why can't you have 1 array that holds (n_rows * 4) products?

Comment: yes that the thing i want ,i will have unlimited product on database in just select*from table,and want to slide them on this slider ,fst row 4 then slide 4 then 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$products = array(); // Products retreived from database

$is_active = true; // Only true for the first iteration
$i = 0;
?>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php foreach($products as $p):?>
<?php if ($i % 4 == 0):?>
    <div class="item<?php if ($is_active) echo ' active'?>">
<?php endif?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-item">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php if (($i+1) % 4 == 0 || $i == count($products)-1):?>
    </div>
<?php endif?>
<?php
$i++;
if ($is_active) $is_active = false;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

This code will generate slides with four products each, and set the `active` class on the first slide.

Comment: Yes thank you Midas this is the thing whic i wanted,

Comment: @AttaullahKhan Great! Accept it as an answer will ya? ;)

Comment: yes where is that option

Comment: hy midas can yo tell me what is this is_active

Comment: When `$is_active` is true, `<div class="item">` will get the `active` class: `<div class="item<?php if ($is_active) echo ' active'?>">`. Only the first item needs the active class, so it is set to false after the first foreach iteration, here: `if ($is_active) $is_active = false;`

Comment: so i  will not need to to add  in databse is_active or some thing for this

Comment: Indeed. The first slide will automatically get the active class assigned.

Comment: yes i got it,thank you so muchh Midas i was trying from one week finaly you make it done,thanks once again

Comment: Easy to understand and simple ... working fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you mean the images of the carousel to be dynamically populated. Obviously you have a table where the carousel image paths are stored and the table is populated dynamically and the corresponding images are either stored or replaced whenever you populate.

And whatever the number of images, you are going to fetch it by while looping. And to run the loop once is nothing hard.

Here it is: [Stop simple JavaScript slideshow after one loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452279/stop-simple-javascript-slideshow-after-one-loop).

Sorry, if i didn't understood you....

Comment: thank you for answer ,yup i know that stup fetching from database but you can see in the code that i run two loop,in the active item theire will be show 4 product ,after that next row wil start automaticly,but it wil be slide to next not break,here is the example that i use http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider

Comment: you can see above in the code this line <!--end of item active!-->
after that i start next row <div class="item">so i wanna to handle this in fst loop i will not run second loop